# How can I arrange calculator buttons in a grid layout within the Xcode15 user interface

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistackview

I've created a StackView in Xcode 15 using ViewController to arrange the calculator buttons in a grid, but I'm encountering an issue where the button sizes automatically shrink. This prevents me from evenly distributing them horizontally.

I learned from a tutorial site that setting the Distribution to 'Fill Equally' would allow for equal spacing. I tried it, but as shown in the image, the buttons ended up shrinking.
(Note: I haven't set any constraints.)
(Note: I've attached images of both the intended final layout and the current state.)

Is there any additional setup required to arrange the buttons neatly? I'd appreciate it if you could suggest a solution that doesn't involve using Swift code!

What I want to do:

[image: The image is what I want to do!]

The result:

[image: The image below shows the state where each button ends up shrinking.]

Comment: `FillEqually` property means that every subviews inside the stack view will have the same size. I thought you didn't set a size for these buttons. Try to make one button width equal to the screen width / 4, then add a ratio with height. Note that stack view also needs constraints too.

Comment: You said you put no constraints, but did you at least put constraints on the stack view?

Comment: May be you need UICollectionView with Composite Layout?

Comment: You would do yourself a favor by working through 5 to 10 tutorials on using `UIStackView`

Comment: @DonMag I've replied on Answer as well, but since this is my first time using StackOverflow, I'm not sure if my reply was delivered, so I'm sending a message here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your started...

Begin by adding your top "display" label, constraining Top/Leading/Trailing:

[image]

Next, add the first "row" of 4 buttons like this - exact size/placement doesn't matter:

[image]

Select the 4 buttons and **embed** in a stack view (horizontal):

[image]

You see that they "shrink" ... that's because a `UIStackView` *arranges* its subviews based on their Intrinsic sizes. Since we haven't done anything specific with sizes yet, that's what we get.

So the next step is to create four more "button rows" -- we can use copy/paste or duplicate -- and embed the five button rows in a Vertical stack view:

[image]

Note: for the time being, we're using two "0" buttons on the bottom row...  we'll fix that as the last step.

Select each "row" stack view and set these properties:

[image]

Select the vertical stack view holding the rows and set these properties:

[image]

Now, constrain that vertical stack view to fill the view:

[image]

and... we now have this layout:

[image]

Let's give the "display label" a Height constraint so it has a little top/bottom padding:

[image]

and then we can set the view and label background colors to Black:

[image]

The bottom "row" is not 4-buttons, so we need to fix that.

- select the two "0" buttons, and embed them in a stack view
- select the "." and "=" buttons, and embed them in a stack view
- set Distribution: Fill Equally on each of the two new stack views
- delete one of the "0" buttons

and we get this:

[image]

Give that a try... if you run into trouble, here is the source for that Storyboard, so you can inspect it: https://pastebin.com/BKQgSr9g

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions. Following your tutorial, I was able to arrange the buttons in a grid. I realized that by stretching the VerticalStackView to fill the screen, the width of the HorizontalStackView inside also expanded, and as a result, each button within it stretched evenly.

Comment: @Wombat - glad it helped... and, yes, when you comment on an answer the "answerer" is notified of the comment :)